# How to Set Global Variable in Laravel (Without Messing up with Migrations)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I just want to Fetch Title and Tagline of the site from `options` table of my Database.
I tried Fetching it from `AppServiceProvider.php` but it shows Error that table does not Exist when I delete all the tables and run `PHP artisan migrate`.
I also tried Session but Finally, it takes me to the old `AppServiceProvider.php` method. It works fine but not when we install the Application fresh and run migration!
This is how my `AppServiceProvider.php` Looks like to get Idea what Exactly I want to do.

```
public function boot()
{
    $site_options = array();

    $site_title = Options::where('option_name','site_title')->first();
    $site_options['site_title'] = $site_title?$site_title->option_value:'Site Title';

    $site_tagline = Options::where('option_name','site_tagline')->first();
    $site_options['site_tagline'] = $site_tagline?$site_tagline->option_value:'A Simple website!';

    view()->share('site_options',$site_options);
}
```

I am searching for the answer on Stackoverflow and everywhere but I don't know what to do. I can also Create constructor on all the Controllers and Fetch the Data but then I have to pass the variables with every view and that makes the code look Bad!
Any Standard Solution for this?
PS: Seeding Does not work when I've this code Added into the `AppServiceProvider.php` nor Migration works. I have to Remove this code from `AppServiceProvider.php` in order to migrate and seed!

Comment: You have to migrate table and seed data

Comment: Yes but Any command containing `php artisan` does not work when I fetch Data from `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a try catch on it?

```
try {
    $site_title = Options::where('option_name','site_title')->first();
    $site_options['site_title'] = $site_title->option_value;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $site_options['site_title'] = 'Site Title';
}
```

Comment: Wooooooo! How can I be so Dumb to not to use Try Catch block! Thanks man!

Comment: Not the most elegant - you could look for the specific exception class it's throwing and catch that in case there's a different problem and this makes it hard to debug.

Comment: @AdarshSojitra p.s. if this solved your problem, feel free to mark the answer as correct

Comment: Done! @Bat Halliday!